# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'matmul'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I just installed python 2.7 on a computer which never had python on it. Been trying to see past questions about this problem but none of them resolved my situation. I tried dot() instead of matmal(), that wokrs but I do not get the answer I think I'm looking for.

```
from numpy import linalg as la
import numpy as np

def myCov(a):
at = a.T
[rows,cols]=np.shape(at);
#    print("rows=", rows, "cols=", cols)
rv = np.ndarray(shape=(rows,rows), dtype=float, order='F')
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(rows):
        rv[i][j] = (np.dot(at[i]-np.mean(at[i]), at[j]-    np.mean(at[j])))/cols
return rv

def pro1(A):
    print("\n\nproblem1:\n")
    c1 = np.cov(A.T, None, True, True);
    c2 = myCov(A);
    print("c1=\n", c1)
    print("c2=\n", c2)
    print("c1=c2", abs(c1-c2) < 0.00001)

def pro2(A):
    print("\n\nproblem2:\n")
    B = myCov(A)
    eigvalues, eigvectors = la.eig(B)

    eigvectors12 = eigvectors[:, 0:2]
    eigvec1 = eigvectors12[:,0]
    eigvec2 = eigvectors12[:,1]

    print("eigvec1=", eigvec1)
    print("eigvec2=", eigvec2)
    projA = np.matmul(A , eigvectors12)

    print("reduced data=", projA)

    covProjA = myCov(projA)

    print("covariance matrix=", covProjA)
    varProjA = np.sum(covProjA)
    varProjA = np.matmul(np.matmul(eigvec1, B), eigvec1.T) +      np.matmul(np.matmul(eigvec2, B), eigvec2.T)

    print("variance=", varProjA)
    print("variance=eigv1+eigv2", abs(varProjA - eigvalues[0] - eigvalues[1]) < 0.00001)

    print ("eigvals=", eigvalues)
    print ("eigvectors=", eigvectors)
def main():
    float_formatter = lambda x: "%.4f" % x
    np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float_kind':float_formatter})
    A = np.loadtxt('magic04.txt', delimiter=',', usecols=range(10))
    print ("input matrix=",A)
    pro1(A)
    pro2(A)
#print("start")
main()
```

I keep getting AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'matmul'.

Comment: What version of numpy do you have? To find out you can run `import numpy as np; np.__version__` from the Python console.

Comment: Numpy vs 1.9.2-8

Answer (score 8):

You are running Numpy 1.9.2-8, but `matmul` was not added until Numpy 1.10.

You should upgrade numpy to the latest version. I don't know what your environment looks like, but if you are using pip, you can run `pip install --upgrade numpy` from the command line.

Comment: Requirement already up-to-date: numpy in site-packages (1.18.1)
If you are using python 3.5+, use @ for mat multiplication.